# Cloud Run remove revision tag through CLI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, tags, gcloud, google-cloud-run, revision

Is there a way to remove a tag(through CLI) that I've set on a cloud run revision when doing a deployment? I can see how to do it through the UI, but I need to include this in my deployment pipeline so it should be through the CLI [image: Delete tag through UI]

My use case is the following:

- deploy a new version of my service with `--no-traffic` flag and `--tag` option in order to make the version accessible
- run test suite on the newly deployed version
- update traffic to point to the new version
- remove the tag from the old/new version

The reason I want to remove those is that all versions that contain tag are kept accessible which is a problem for me since I'm also using the `min-instances` option.

Edit: I was using incorrectly labels instead of tags here.

Comment: I've not tried this but it's possible that you could [`get`](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/namespaces.services/get) your service, revise the labels and then [`put`](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/namespaces.services/replaceService) it back

Comment: You talk about label and tag. Can you be more precise because it's 2 different things!

Comment: Why don't you want to create a new version of the service? In general, pretty much any change to a deployed Cloud Run service requires you to deploy a new version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `--remove-tags` can be used with the `update-traffic` command. Since every tag can be assigned only to a single run revision this is the correct way to remove a tag from a revision.

** Always using the same tag for deployment preview/testing also works in the above use case since using the same tag on the latest revision effectively removes this tag from older revisions.

Answer (score 0):

This command below:

```
gcloud run services update-traffic <service>
```

With this flag below **can remove one or more tags from one or more revisions**:

```
--remove-tags <tag>,…
```

Now, there are **two revisions "editor-v2-0-0"** with **three tags "green", "orange" and "yellow"** and **"editor-v1-0-0"** with **three tags "blue", "black" and "white"**:

[image]

Then, I run the command as shown below to remove **one tag "orange"** from **the revision "editor-v2-0-0"**:

```
gcloud run services update-traffic editor --remove-tags orange
```

Now, **one tag "orange"** is removed from **the revision "editor-v2-0-0"** as shown below:

[image]

Next, I run the command as shown below to remove **one tag "green"** from **the revision "editor-v2-0-0"** and **two tags "blue" and "white"** from **the revision "editor-v1-0-0"**:

```
gcloud run services update-traffic editor \
  --remove-tags green,blue,white
```

Now, **one tag "green"** is removed from **the revision "editor-v2-0-0"** and **two tags "blue" and "white"** are removed from **the revision "editor-v1-0-0"** as shown below:

[image]

*Be careful, if there are **one or more empty strings before or after a comma in a list of values**, there is an error:

So, if an empty string is before a comma:

```
gcloud run services update-traffic editor \
  --remove-tags green ,blue,white
                  // An empty string before a comma
```

Then, there is an error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.run.services.update-traffic) unrecognized arguments: ,blue,white

And if an empty string is after a comma:

```
gcloud run services update-traffic editor \
  --remove-tags green, blue,white　　　　　　　　　　　　　　                 
                   // An empty string after a comma
```

Then, there is an error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.run.services.update-traffic) unrecognized arguments: blue,white

So, don't put **one or more empty strings before or after a comma in a list of values**:

```
gcloud run services update-traffic editor \
  --remove-tags green,blue,white
                  // No empty strings 
                  // before or after a comma
```

Next, this command below:

```
gcloud run services update-traffic <service>
```

With this flag below **can remove all tags** from **all revisions**:

```
--clear-tags
```

Now again, there are **two revisions "editor-v2-0-0"** with **three tags "green", "orange" and "yellow"** and **"editor-v1-0-0"** with **three tags "blue", "black" and "white"**:

[image]

Then, including the flag above, I run the full command as shown below to remove **all the tags** from **all the revisions**:

```
gcloud run services update-traffic editor --clear-tags
```

Now, **all the tags** are removed from **all the revisions** as shown below:

[image]